# Saving JSON Objects into MySQL DB in Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I have the following JSON. I am a newbie to both JSON and Laravel. I want to save each of the array objects like `LineNum`, `StationName` and `StopNum` into the DB. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been able to parse, but unable to save them to DB.

```
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n <br />" ;

        $trainDetail->Route = "$key";

    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n <br />";
        $trainDetail->StopNumber = "$key";
        $trainDetail->StationName  = "$val";
    }
}
```

The Route is not storing the `LineNum`, the `StopNumb` is not storing the correct value.

Here is the JSON I am working on.

```
{"LineNum1":[{"StopNumber":"MN218","StationName":"ABCD"}],"LineNum2":[{"StopNumber":"MN244","StationName":"XYZ"}],"LineNum3":[{"StopNumber":"MN220","StationName":"DEFCG"},{"StopNumber":"MN318","StationName":"QWERTY"}]}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: saving JSON object is a bit tough task in Laravel. why don't you modify your query just for getting an array using `->pluck('field');`

Comment: can you help me with an example.? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A normal query will return something like this,

```
[{"ID":"1","Code":"ECX4236"},{"ID":"10","Code":"LWJ3154"},{"ID":"11","Code":"TTX4201"},{"ID":"12","Code":"TTY2545"},{"ID":"13","Code":"RRA2553"}]
```

If you use Laravel's query format.

```
$items = DB::table('Items')->where('isActive','=',1)->pluck('Code');
```

this returns an array.

```
["ECX4236","LWJ3154","TTX4201","TTY2545","RRA2553"]
```

You can easily enter this into a database using Laravel. This is what I do.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. I am accessing a URL which returns the JSON response.
I want to parse the response and save the data into DB fields. 
for eg. in my original JSON 
'{"LineNum1":[{"StopNumber":"MN218","StationName":"ABCD"}],"LineNum2":[{"StopNumber":"MN244","StationName":"XYZ"}],"LineNum3":[{"StopNumber":"MN220","StationName":"DEFCG"},{"StopNumber":"MN318","StationName":"QWERTY"}]}
'
I want to capture the LineNum's and StopNumber's and StationName's into their respective DB fields.  I guess your solution would not work for me.